# UIView drawRect not called on autorotate

Tags: ios, uiview, core-graphics, autorotate

I have a custom view that is added to the view controllers view

```
[self.view addSubview:myView];
```

In the view I added :

```
self.autoresizingMask = self.superview.autoresizingMask;
```

But my view's DrawRect method is not called when auto rotating... Why? I need the view's bounds to change so I can redraw it on auto rotate ...

Answer (score 0):

What is the value of self.superview.autoresizingMask? That's probably why nothing's changing. Either explicitly set the autoresizing mask to what you want it to do, or if that doesn't provide enough control, use the ViewController's willAnimationRotationToInterfaceOrientation method to explicitly set the subview's frame or trigger a setNeedsDisplay: on the subview.

Comment: the only way I could fix this is by setting the autoresizeMask in the view controller... apparently in the new xcode you can't set it in IB ... it just said some stuff about "hugging priority" ...

Comment: Yeah, that's the new iOS 6.0 auto layout stuff. You can still set the autoresizing mask in code. Clearly, the ViewController's view didn't have an autoresizing mask set on it. As long as the view controller in question is the root view controller, then your solution shouldn't affect anything, but the better solution would have been to set the autoresizing mask on the subview directly in code or to manually lay out your views using either **[UIViewController willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:]** or **[UIViewController viewWillLayoutSubviews]**.